# Assertion failure in - GPUImagePicture

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Why with the following code would I get an Assertion failure:

```
if (Butten.tag==1) {
        //int errorCount = 0;
        //UIImage *filterImage;
        GPUImageAmatorkaFilter *ColorMatrix=[[GPUImageAmatorkaFilter alloc]init];
        [ColorMatrix prepareForImageCapture];
        UIImage *filterImage=[ColorMatrix imageByFilteringImage:img_MainImage];

        //while (! (filterImage = [ColorMatrix imageByFilteringImage:img_MainImage]) ) {
         //   ++errorCount;
        //}

        //if (errorCount > 0) {
            //NSLog(@"GPUImageiOSBlurFilter imageByFilteringImage button clicked:");
        //}
        vw_MainImage.image=filterImage;
        image_Edited =filterImage;
        lbl_MenuType.text=[arr_Effectname objectAtIndex:0];
        filterImage=nil;
        free((__bridge void *)(filterImage));
    }
```

Error is:

**Assertion failure in -[GPUImagePicture initWithCGImage:smoothlyScaleOutput:removePremultiplication:], /Users/darrenedwards/Desktop/app/Source/iOS/GPUImagePicture.m:94**

Line 94 is:

```
 NSAssert( widthOfImage > 0 && heightOfImage > 0, @"Passed image must not be empty - it should be at least 1px tall and wide");
```

Comment: Because apparently the width and/or height of the image you passed was 0

Comment: Great stuff, thanks - how can I set the height and width of an image? I am totally new to this - Its seems to only happen when its a new image being taken only. What snippet of code usual defines the height and width in XCode object-C for a photo being taken?

Comment: The most likely cause is that you didn’t actually pass a picture.

Comment: Interesting.. An image is taken, then when I try apply a filter the above error
 appears. It won't however appear a second time as long as I don't terminate the app (if that makes sense) maybe something to do with how the image is stored?